# DBT ref within a for loop

Tags: sql, jinja2, etl, dbt

I have a list of subqueries in my dbt project ["base","table_1", "table_2", "table_3"...].

I would like to join them all on a common column, id.

I would like to avoid repetition by doing this using for loop macro. My problem is, I get syntax errors when I try to reference the subquery name {{sub}} within {{ref}}.

Here is the code I was trying.

```
{% set subs = ["table_1", "table_2", "table_3"] %}


SELECT
{% for sub in subs %}
    {{sub}}.* EXCEPT (id),
{% endfor %}
base.*
FROM {{ref('base')}} as base
{% for sub in subs %}
    LEFT JOIN {{ref({{sub}})}} as {{sub}}
    ON {{sub}}.id = base.id
{% endfor %}
```

I get a syntax error

`expected token ':', got '}'`

And if I change to

`LEFT JOIN {{ref("'"{{sub}}"'")}} as {{sub}}`

I get this error

`expected token ',', got '{'`

Finally with

`LEFT JOIN {{ref("{{sub}}")}} as {{sub}}`

I get

`Model depends on a node named '{{sub}}' which was not found`

Here are some pages I read but couldn't see a solution

[Using a string as an argument in a Jinja macro in dbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052155/using-a-string-as-an-argument-in-a-jinja-macro-in-dbt)

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ref()`, you are already inside an expression clause (`{{..}}`), so you do not need to add another expression clause to refer to your subs.

```sql
{% set subs = ["table_1", "table_2", "table_3"] %}


SELECT
{% for sub in subs %}
    {{sub}}.* EXCEPT (id),
{% endfor %}
base.*
FROM {{ref('base')}} as base
{% for sub in subs %}
    LEFT JOIN {{ ref(sub) }} as {{sub}}
    ON {{sub}}.id = base.id
{% endfor %}
```

---

However, if your subs are really subqueries with the use of the `with` sql clause in that same model, you don't need to use `ref()` because they are not dbt models. You can check the documentation for a better understanding of [`ref()`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref)

```sql
{% set subs = ["table_1", "table_2", "table_3"] %}


SELECT
{% for sub in subs %}
    {{sub}}.* EXCEPT (id),
{% endfor %}
base.*
FROM {{ref('base')}} as base
{% for sub in subs %}
    LEFT JOIN {{ sub }}
    ON {{sub}}.id = base.id
{% endfor %}
```